# Discord bot does not load or give error in Node.js

Tags: node.js, discord.js

Discord bot does not load or give error, I was unable to start a bot for a large project after several attempts so I created another folder and redid the entire discord.js installation process (and also reinstalled node.js) and this new project (with no function other than client.on ( 'ready' ...)) also didn't open, is there a problem with my machine, can anyone tell me what it is? It happened out of nowhere without restarting the computer.
Code:

```
const Discord = require('discord.js')
const client = new Discord.Client()
client.on('ready', () => {
  console.log("ready")
})
client.login("Token")
```

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't seem to be a local problem, but from Discord, I tried it with another Discord Application and it worked correctly, I had to delete the bot application and create it again to work. I don't know what caused the bot to crash.